# Updating document.title every second

Tags: javascript, html

```
<script>
window.setInterval(function(){ document.title = "site - " + msToTime();}, 1000);
function msToTime() {
  var milliseconds = parseInt((remainingTime % 1000) / 100),
    seconds = parseInt((remainingTime / 1000) % 60),
    minutes = parseInt((remainingTime / (1000 * 60)) % 60),
    hours = parseInt((remainingTime / (1000 * 60 * 60)) % 24);

  hours = (hours < 10) ? "0" + hours : hours;
  minutes = (minutes < 10) ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
  seconds = (seconds < 10) ? "0" + seconds : seconds;

  return hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds + "." + milliseconds;
}
</script>
```

remainingTime would bring however much seconds left in the timer (00:07:19.7). When I change document.title to alert(), it would successfully give alerts every second, but I want the tab title to update every second. How would I accomplish this?

Comment: Is that all of your code? I'm getting an error testing it. -> "remainingTime is not defined"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go! That's what you wanted? I edited your code adding the functionality of time, test it! changing every millisecond.

P.S - If i were you i would delete the milliseconds. Stays more clean without it

```js
    window.setInterval(function(){ document.title = "rumseytime - " + msToTime();}, 1000);
    function msToTime() {
      var remainingTime = new Date();
      var milliseconds = remainingTime.getMilliseconds();
        seconds = remainingTime.getSeconds();
        minutes = remainingTime.getMinutes();
        hours = remainingTime.getHours();
    
      hours = (hours < 10) ? "0" + hours : hours;
      minutes = (minutes < 10) ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
      seconds = (seconds < 10) ? "0" + seconds : seconds;
    
      return hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds + "." + milliseconds;
      
    }
```

Comment: I was trying to get the timer results to show but this helped me figure it out. Thank you!

Comment: @Teddy Hwang -- When you're using setInterval, don't forget to clear it as well (recommended practice), like this: var myVar = window.setInterval(yourFunction, timerValue); and then call clearInterval(myVar) when you're done with the interval logic (like navigating to other page or on some button click etc). Reference: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp